# Thread input queue

Tags: windows, winapi

What's a "thread input queue"? I've seen it mentioned on MSDN a few times, and can stop wondering whether it's simply the message queue for a window, that's created by the thread they mean, or something else.

An example:

> The WH_MOUSE_LL hook enables you to monitor mouse input events about
>   to be posted in a **thread input queue**.

Comment: From my understanding, what I learned in the 1990s, this is similar to a keyboard buffer in DOS - If the user inputs faster than your process can handle it, the OS puts the inputs (mouse, keyboard) into a queue so they don't get lost.

Comment: @UweKeim, That would roughly mean, that when I ex. Left-click my mouse, the event is first added to the thread input queue. Once it's been dequeued, and done what it should, it'll create a message `WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK`, and enqueue it in the specificed window' message queue? - So all in all, in order to enqueue a mouse event, it needs first to go through the thread input queue, and it's logic - or am I all wrong?

Comment: Yes, that is how I picture it in my mind. I'm not fully clear how "thread" and "window" differes here, but I'm sure someone will post a much more detailed answer :-)

Comment: [Here is an example of the core message loop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644928(v=vs.85).aspx#creating_loop).

Comment: @UweKeim, I'm aware of how the message loop etc. works (but thanks anyway! :)). The thing I'm confused about, is how thread input queue fits in this whole model, and whether the items in there need to be processed, in order to add the equivalent message to the thread message queue. - Although, I must admit I'm getting more and more confused... some MSDN articles says that I can GetMessage/PeekMessage in order to retrieve the input from a thread input queue... as far as I know, GetMessage/PeekMessage is to get messages from a thread message queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, note that windows don't have individual message queues; messages for a window are deposited in the message queue of the associated thread.

[According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632585%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), keyboard and mouse input messages are sent to the message queue of the thread associated with the relevant window.  So I believe that "thread input queue" is simply another way of saying "thread message queue".

EDIT: Raymond has pointed out (see comments) that input can be redirected to a different thread's message queue using the AttachThreadInput function.  So, "thread input queue" means whichever message queue is receiving input for the given thread; by default this is the same thread's message queue, but it can be the message queue for a different thread.

Comment: Each thread has a message queue. Each thread *group* has an input queue.

Comment: @RaymondChen, Any documentation somewhere, that explains it?

Comment: For a 16-bit view, see "GetMessage and PeekMessage Internals" by Bob Gunderson. In Win16, there is a single system-wide input queue, but in Win32, each thread group has its own input queue. (Thread groups are created by the AttachThreadInput function. You wondered what that function was for, huh?) See also "Five Things Every Win32 Programmer Should Know."

Comment: @RaymondChen, What if you don't use the `AttachThreadInput` function? Will the thread just have a input queue, and once another thread has been attached, it will share that queue with the thread? - Also... why do we need the input queue in the first place? Why not simply use the message queue? - I'm surprised, that the input queue is not documented anywhere.

Comment: Not sure how you intend to attach a thread without AttachThreadInput. The input queue is not called out by name, but it's presence is described in the documentation for GetMessage/PeekMessage where it talks about the order in which messages are processed. Note that posted messages go ahead of input messages.

Comment: @RaymondChen, I meant that, if you just had a single thread (no threads attached) - would it then have an input queue too? Just to clarify, what the input queue actually is: The input queue, is simply the internal queue inside the "message queue" that holds the messages for input? - And once you use `AttachThreadInput`, you make  multiple threads share the same internal input queue somehow?

Comment: Each thread has a message queue, and each thread group has an input queue. If you have a thread group with only one thread, then there is one message queue and one input queue.

Comment: @RaymondChen, Ah - I see. But am I wrong, when I say that the input queue is the internal queue inside the "message queue", wherein all input messages is enqueued? - Or is the message queue and the input queue two totally different queues?

Comment: They behave as if they are separate queues: posted messages go to the end of the message queue, and input goes to the end of the input queue. It doesn't really matter how they are implemented internally, since it is the external behavior that is what is relevant here.

Comment: @RaymondChen, If I press some key on my keyboard, the driver will translate it into some virtual key identifier, which is then wrapped into some message and sent to the system message queue. The system message loop will then, add the message to the thread message queue - right? But where does the input queue come in? When will the input get added to the input queue? After the message loop, like the thread message queue, or will it be added directly after the driver translation?

Comment: After you press a key, it goes into the system input queue. The input system then decides which thread group should get the message, and it gets transferred to that thread group's input queue.

Comment: @RaymondChen, But... if I press a key, there'll also be a message? - So if I press a key, it will be translated and then both be added to the system input queue, and the system message queue?

Comment: The keypress message goes into the system input queue, and then to the application input queue. As I've already explained, the documentation for `GetMessage` and `PeekMessage` discuss when the input queue is consulted. I don't know why you keep bringing up the system message queue, and now you introduced translation out of nowhere. Translation happens when the application calls `TranslateMessage` is called. I don't think this discussion is getting anywhere.

Comment: @RaymondChen, According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646267(v=VS.85).aspx and my own tests, then each time I press some key on my keyboard, a message is added to the thread message queue...

Comment: If you read the documentation, you'll see that `GetMessage` and `PeekMessage` retrieve messages from both the message queue and input queue. And as I've already noted, most people don't talk about the input queue explicitly; they mentally merge it with the message queue even though they are technically different things. I'm tired of this discussion and will no longer reply.

Comment: @RaymondChen, Thanks! That's what confused me. :) - I appreciate your help and time. - Please make an answer with your last comment, and I'll mark it.

Answer (score 1):

The real answer is slightly more complicated than the logical abstractions [offered by the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632585%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). I can answer in more detail than what has been confirmed in the comments of the accepted answer.

Yes, there are two sets of messages.  There is a "post message queue" and an "input message queue."  The latter contains a list of raw mouse and keyboard message events. The former contains posted and synthesized messages.

Internally, they're both just lists, but the input message list is contained within a larger structure referenced internally as the "input queue."  The structure contains data about the logical queue plus a pointer the the raw input message list.

They're also interchangeably called the "application queue" and "system queue", respectively.

`GetMessage()` processes them separately.

`THREADINFO` contains a pointer directly to the post message list/queue.  This is scanned if `QS_POSTMESSAGE` is set.

If either the `QS_INPUT` or `QS_EVENT` queue statues are set, the input list/queue is scanned by getting the initial queue structure pointer from `THREADINFO` and then the pointer to the input list from that queue structure.  Weird, I know.

If the `QS_TIMER` queue status flag is set, `GetMessage()` (or `PeekMessage()`) will actually have to launch of a scan of the full non-kernel timer list to find the earliest timer with an alerted status that "belongs" to whoever called `GetMessage()`.  The queues don't actually store anything about which timer fired.  They only related information they store is the `QS_TIMER` flag and a count of the number of timers triggered (so that `GetMessage()` knows when to clear the `QS_TIMER` queue status once it has synthesized a message for the last triggered timer available.)

The other synthesized messages work similarly in that they're based on data stored outside the actual lists of queue messages, but still "in" the other data in the queue structures themselves.